# How can I choose all fields in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The following is working with one field:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%" + txtBox.Text + "%'";
```

Now I need more than one field. Is there a way to express this like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1, field2 LIKE '%" + txtBox.Text + "%'";
```

Or something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE * LIKE '%" + txtBox.Text + "%'";
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you want to check multiple columns. Use `AND` if both condition should be satisfy, use `OR` if any one condition should satisfy, based on your requirement.  Check the below select statements.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1  LIKE 'Value1' AND field2 LIKE 'Value2';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1  LIKE 'Value1' OR field2 LIKE 'Value2';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE  
field1 LIKE '%" + txtBox.Text + "%' OR 
field2 LIKE '%" + txtBox.Text + "%' OR
...... OR 
fieldn LIKE '%" + txtBox.Text + "%'";
```

You have to list all the fields separately and check the condition.